# Organizing millions of measurements in database tables

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to figure best way to store measurement data:

1. I have more than 50 instruments
2. Instruments are independent, no need to link data
3. Every instrument generates one record every minute
4. Every record has about 1400 measurements (float values)
5. Every record has unique time of measurement
6. I will use queries for selecting data between time (in 99% of cases)
7. I will use queries to select several types of measurements for period of at most one month (5 - 30 measurement types)
8. Sometimes I will query all measurements for specific date and time
9. Not all data are equally important. There are about 100-200 measurement types that will be selected in most of the cases
10. I'll be recording for at least 6 months
11. Inserting is not an issue
12. I'm using SQL Server 2012

What would be the best way to go for?

1. I'm thinking of creating 7 tables for each instrument. First table could contain only the most important measurement types (200 columns). Remaining tables would contain about 200 columns each. How to index data most efficiently if I would use Join for selecting from multiple tables? This way I would have 1440 rows per day.
2. Other approach would be to create two tables. First would contain primary key created from Time. I would put in second table one row for each measurement. This way I would have 2M rows per day.

Comment: Is there a requirement to store all 1400 measurements?  What if only summarized data was stored? If the reports will be using the summary data, it reduces the storage need, and allows the reports to be generated faster.

Comment: I must store all measurements.I have option for reducing recording interval to one month.

Comment: The space requirement is not an issue. I have 2M measurements per instruments per day. I have similar system running for almost a year, but I'm storing data every 10 minutes. I'm using MySQL server for database engine. Database has grown to almost 20 Gbytes.

Comment: I'm expecting large increase of instruments  when project goes to production phase (up to  300 devices). Recording setting will be limited by 100 GB database size per year.

Comment: How are you planning to pull out the data? With that many records you will probably want to ignore normalization in favor of a Data Warehouse-style architecture. Retrieval should be a consideration from a 100GB database.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating just one table. What you want to achieve with the "time" table could be achieved with in-database compression of column values and partitioning of your table by months. What you want to achieve by splitting the data into various tables you could probably achieve with indexes.